# How to align  Currency valus (String) to Right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to align currency valus (strings) to right. Like this

```
  7.50
  6.50
 10.00
120.00
```

How could I do something like this. I am struggling to find a solution.

Comment: lblForItem.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're dumping text to console/file? Then you may want to format the strings using

```
NSString * output = [NSString stringWithFromat:@"%6.2f", value];
```

This will give you a 6 digit number with 2 decimal places regardless of the value:

so an '8' would become

[  8.00] (two spaces in front)

and 128.12 would be

[128.12] (no spaces in front)

You can change the %6.2 values to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a UILabel, you can do `label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight`

Comment: Thanks for the help, But I'm using a concatenate string. NOT UILabels

Comment: What? What type of UIView subclass are you using to display the text?

Comment: I'm doing this for printing a receipt via air printer. I am using a concatenate string like this ******* [strBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@    %@",[arrItemQuantityList objectAtIndex:i],[arrPricesList objectAtIndex:i]]; ************ arrPricesList contains the prices of items which I want to align to right

Comment: When you concatenate strings you use NSString or subclasses. In them isn't possible to set any alignment. You can do it only in your UI-class (e.g. UILabel).

Comment: You have to do the text alignment on a graphical display element (typically a subclass of UIView). You can't do the text alignment of an NSString because there is no graphical element to an NSString, it needs to be in some sort of container (UILabel, UITextView, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using following code to print (for air print ) : -

```
UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:yourString];
[textFormatter setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
```

For [more Info](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISimpleTextPrintFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).